# Are there faster, more-memory-efficient alternatives to encodeJpg, decodeJpg to convert Package:image/image images to Flutter widget images?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a topographic map image (10089x7786 pixels;  27MB in JPEG, 56MB in PNG) on which I draw small squares and add a crosshairs image at specific pixel points to show the track and current location of a GPS.   I use image/image package to do this.  I plan to use JPEG or PNG depending on which is faster and more reliable.

The issue is that encode and decode while acceptable on the Linux machine,  is too slow and prone to failure on the android - depending on the map size.

My question is:  Are there faster ways to convert from image format to flutter format using less memory?   Working with image/image package is fast and easy but every time the GPS moves, I have to convert the updated  image to Flutter using either encodeJpg (bombs) or encodePng (too slow) in order to display it on the android device.

My results and machines they were run on for a sub-test are below.

Linux ==> X86, 64-bit,                  1.6 GHz,   23 GB memory   1 TB disk
phone ==>  Samsung Galaxy A12           2.3 MHz,   5.6 GB memory  128 GB disk

### LINUX SUMMARY PNG => 56 MB image

download PNG  7 sec
decode PNG to image/image  6 sec
encode image/image to flutter 14 sec
TOTAL = 27 sec

### LINUX SUMMARY JPEG => 27 MB image

download JPEG  3 sec
decode JPEG to image/image  6 sec
encode image/image to flutter JPEG 10 sec
TOTAL = 19 sec

### ANDROID  SUMMARY PNG => 56 MB image

download .PNG  8 sec
decode PNG to image/image  45 sec
encode image/image to flutter  84 sec
TOTAL = 137 sec

### ANDROID  SUMMARY JPEG  => 27 MB image

Flutter Exception: Out of Memory
on decode JPEG to image/image

### Code Snippets

DOWNLOAD - called once from initState.  Speed not critical.

```
download() async {
    t.timestamp('Download Started');
     String url =
        "http://www.erybus.com/oz3/Canada/topographic/routes/LakeBonavista2/082j16.jpg";
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    final appDir = await path_provider.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final phoneDir1 = path.join(appDir.path, 'phonetemp');
    final phoneDir2 = path.join(appDir.path, 'phone');
    bool phonethere = await io.Directory(phoneDir1).exists();
    if (!phonethere) {
        await io.Directory(phoneDir1).create();
        await io.Directory(phoneDir2).create();
    }
    final localPath = path.join(appDir.path, 'phone/082j16.jpg');
    final csvFile = io.File(localPath);
    await csvFile.writeAsBytes(response.bodyBytes);
    t.timestamp('Download Finished');
```

DECODE FROM JPG/PNG TO IMAGE/IMAGE  - called once from initState.  Speed not critical.

```
    mapid = mapid + ".jpg";
    io.Directory appDir =
         await path_provider.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String mappath = path.join(appDir.path, 'phone', mapid); // phone/082j16.jpg
    print('mappath = $mappath');
    mantrack = await img.decodeJpgFile(mappath);
```

ENCODE FROM IMAGE/IMAGE TO FLUTTER WIDGET  - called on each build when gps changes.   Speed critical.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    t.timestamp('#8 WIDGET BUILD START  ok = $ok');
    /* copy mantrack & add crosshairs */
    if (ok) {
        img.Image mapcopy = img.copyRotate(mantrack.mantrack!, angle: 0); //copy
        img.Image mapshow = mantrack.addcrosshairs(mapcopy, Pixel(7652, 1784));
        return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(title: Text("peter61 deleteme")),
            body: InteractiveViewer(
                minScale: 0.5,
                maxScale: 100.0,
                child: Image.memory(
                    img.encodeJpg(mapshow),
                    height: double.infinity,
                    width: double.infinity,
```

Comment: SO is a **question** and answer site. Note that *question* is singular, not plural. It is not a *Here's my numbered list of questions* site. If you have more than one question, they need to be in separate posts. You may want to go back and review the [help] pages to better your understanding of how the site works.

Comment: Now edited so it is one question.

Comment: A couple of suggestions since I can't provide a full answer as long as your question is closed. 1. Don't save the image to a file unless you're going to use it later. Even if you do save the image, use the raw data that you download directly. Your program is probably spending a lot of time waiting for slow File IO to complete in your "non-critical" sections. 2. Don't encode your image after doing your image transformation in `build`. Encoding is slow and unnecessary as `Image.memory` the just has to decode it right back. Use the `RawImage` widget instead to display.

Comment: Sounds like you should use [tiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiled_web_map) instead of one giant image.

Answer (score 2):

Christopher Moore's suggestion to use RawImage is essentially correct.    I ran a series of tests and came to the following conclusion.

FASTER: yes, by using RawImage, dart.ui, and the "Convert a Dart Image Library Image to a Flutter UI Image" algorithm shown in
"https://github.com/brendan-duncan/image/blob/main/doc/flutter.md"
one can avoid the encodeJpg and subsequent decodeJpg as suggested by Christopher Moore.  The good news is that on the same github site,  Brendan-Duncan promises  "I will be releasing an extension library that will simplify working with this library and Flutter."

Unfortunately, my sRGB format in the image library had to be converted to rgba8888 format for RawImage taking an extra 5 seconds (30%).   I was surprised RawImage did not accept sRGB.

The encode/decode would probably be faster if one used .bmp instead of .jpg or .png.   However, the download would be slower and the amount of disk storage higher so I did not test this.

LESS MEMORY: AFAIK - no.   I still had to use brendan-duncan's decodeJpgFile() to convert my downloaded .jpg file to an image.  My attempts to convert a .jpg file to a sRGB file using dart.ui failed miserably.   I had to purchase a new phone with more memory in order to make this program work.  To avoid future crashes,  I will have to put in phone size checks before allowing the app to run elsewhere.

My test results, devices tested, and some source code snippets are below.

### TEST IMAGE

```
Canada Topographic Map image (id=082j16) found on erybus.com

map 082j16 is sRGB (standard Red, Green, Blue)  
 = 10089 x 7786 pixels = 78,552,954 pixels  
 = 10089 x 7786 x 3 channels = 235 MB (235,658,862 bytes)  

can be accessed off erybus.com as   
 082j16.jpg = 27.3MB (27,331,477 bytes)  
 082j16.png = 56.2MB (56,234,914 bytes)  
 082j16.bmp = 235.7MB  (235,666,786 bytes)
```

### TEST DEVICES

```
1. HP laptop running Debian Linux 
    12GB RAM + 12GB Swap(virtual memory) 1TB disk

2. Samsung Galaxy A12 
     3GB RAM + 4GB Swap(virtual memory) 32GB disk

3. Google Pixel 8 Pro 
     12GB RAM + 6GB Swap(virtual memory)  256GB disk
```

### peter61.dart: TEST using encodePng decodePng

- #1-#2:: 082j16.png download and save ==> writeAsBytes(response.bodyBytes)
- #2-#3:: convert to image ==> mantrack = decodePngFile()
- #3-#8:: make copy, add crosshairs ==> img.mapshow
- #8-#999:: InteractiveViewer(...img.encodePng(mapshow)...)

Samsung Galaxy A12

```
I/flutter ( 5432): #0 ***** START INITSTATE ******* = 0 seconds
I/flutter ( 5432): #1 ***** START DOWNLOAD ******* = 0 seconds
I/flutter ( 5432): #8 WIDGET BUILD START  ok = false = 1 seconds
I/flutter ( 5432): #2 ***** START MANTRACK.INIT ******* = 6 seconds
I/flutter ( 5432): #3 ***** START MANTRACK.ADDTRACK ******* = 51 seconds
I/flutter ( 5432): #8 WIDGET BUILD START  ok = true = 51 seconds
I/flutter ( 5432): #999 **** BUILD COMPLETE ******* = 135 seconds
```

Linux emulator

```
flutter: #0 ***** START INITSTATE ******* = 0 seconds
flutter: #1 ***** START DOWNLOAD ******* = 0 seconds
flutter: #8 WIDGET BUILD START  ok = false = 0 seconds
flutter: #2 ***** START MANTRACK.INIT ******* = 5 seconds
flutter: #3 ***** START MANTRACK.ADDTRACK ******* = 11 seconds
flutter: #8 WIDGET BUILD START  ok = true = 11 seconds
flutter: #999 **** BUILD COMPLETE ******* = 26 seconds
```

Pixel 8 Pro

```
I/flutter (15534): #0 ***** START INITSTATE ******* = 0 seconds
I/flutter (15534): #1 ***** START DOWNLOAD ******* = 0 seconds
I/flutter (15534): #8 WIDGET BUILD START  ok = false = 0 seconds
I/flutter (15534): #2 ***** START MANTRACK.INIT ******* = 3 seconds
I/flutter (15534): #3 ***** START MANTRACK.ADDTRACK ******* = 9 seconds
I/flutter (15534): #8 WIDGET BUILD START  ok = true = 9 seconds
I/flutter (15534): #999 **** BUILD COMPLETE ******* = 25 seconds
```

### peter64.dart: TEST  RawImage + brendan-duncan algorithm on github

see [github](https://github.com/brendan-duncan/image/blob/main/doc/flutter.md)

- 082j16.png download and save ==> writeAsBytes(response.bodyBytes)
- convert to image ==>  decodeJpgFile()
- make copy, add crosshairs etc ==> Brendan Duncan library
- InteractiveViewer(...Raw Image...)

Samsung Galaxy A12

```
I/flutter (26961): #0 ***** START INITSTATE ******* = 0 seconds
I/flutter (26961): #1 ***** START DOWNLOAD 082j16******* = 0 seconds
I/flutter (26961): #8 WIDGET BUILD START  ok = false = 0 seconds
I/flutter (26961): #999 **** BUILD COMPLETE ******* = 1 seconds
I/flutter (26961): #1 ***** END DOWNLOAD 082j16 ******* = 3 seconds
I/flutter (26961): #3 ***** START DECODEJPGFILE() ******* = 3 seconds
Lost connection to device.
```

Linux emulator

```
flutter: #0 ***** START INITSTATE ******* = 0 seconds
flutter: #1 ***** START DOWNLOAD 082j16******* = 0 seconds
flutter: #8 WIDGET BUILD START  ok = false = 0 seconds
flutter: #999 **** BUILD COMPLETE ******* = 0 seconds
flutter: #1 ***** END DOWNLOAD 082j16 ******* = 2 seconds
flutter: #3 ***** START DECODEJPGFILE() ******* = 2 seconds
flutter: #3 ***** END DECODEJPGFILE() ******* = 9 seconds
flutter: #4 ***** START CROSSHAIRS INIT  ******* = 9 seconds
flutter: #4 ***** END CROSSHAIRS INIT  ******* = 9 seconds
flutter: #5 ***** START ADDTRACK ******* = 9 seconds
flutter: #5 ***** END ADDTRACK ******* = 9 seconds
flutter: SS#1 ***** START ADD CROSSHAIRS ******* = 9 seconds
flutter: SS#1 ***** END ADD CROSSHAIRS ******* = 9 seconds
flutter: SS#1 ***** START IMG TO UI IMAGE ******* = 9 seconds
flutter: SS#1 ***** END IMG TO UI IMAGE ******* = 15 seconds
flutter: #8 WIDGET BUILD START  ok = true = 15 seconds
flutter: #999 **** BUILD COMPLETE ******* = 15 seconds
```

Pixel 8 Pro

```
I/flutter (25695): #0 ***** START INITSTATE ******* = 0 seconds
I/flutter (25695): #1 ***** START DOWNLOAD 082j16******* = 0 seconds
I/flutter (25695): #8 WIDGET BUILD START  ok = false = 0 seconds
I/flutter (25695): #999 **** BUILD COMPLETE ******* = 0 seconds
I/flutter (25695): #1 ***** END DOWNLOAD 082j16 ******* = 2 seconds
I/flutter (25695): #3 ***** START DECODEJPGFILE() ******* = 2 seconds
I/flutter (25695): #3 ***** END DECODEJPGFILE() ******* = 10 seconds
I/flutter (25695): #4 ***** START CROSSHAIRS INIT  ******* = 10 seconds
I/flutter (25695): #4 ***** END CROSSHAIRS INIT  ******* = 10 seconds
I/flutter (25695): #5 ***** START ADDTRACK ******* = 10 seconds
I/flutter (25695): SS#1 ***** START ADD CROSSHAIRS ******* = 10 seconds
I/flutter (25695): SS#1 ***** START IMG TO UI IMAGE ******* = 10 seconds
I/flutter (25695): SS#1 ***** END IMG TO UI IMAGE ******* = 15 seconds
I/flutter (25695): #8 WIDGET BUILD START  ok = true = 15 seconds
I/flutter (25695): #999 **** BUILD COMPLETE ******* = 16 seconds
```

peter61_main.dart

```
// peter61.dasrt
// test package:image/image.dart
// brendan-duncan github
// Peter Thompson Oct 2023
//
// AND DON'T FORGET ...
// dart pub add image
// dart pub add path_provider
// dart pub add path
// dart pub add http
//
// THIS WORKS  but man is it ever SLOW
// Use .png because .jpg crashes on "insufficient memory"

import 'package:flutter/material.dart'; // for BOILERPLATE runApp() etc
import 'timestamp.dart';
import 'mantrack.dart';
import 'datamodelgps.dart';
import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:path/path.dart' as path; // save cuc.csv
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart' as path_provider;
import 'dart:io' as io; //for file read/write

Time t = new Time();

// BOILERPLATE
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: Home());
  }
}

//ignore: must_be_immutable
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  ManTrack mantrack = ManTrack();
  bool ok = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    t.timestamp('#0 ***** START INITSTATE *******');
    initiate();
    super.initState();
  }

  initiate() async {
    // download 082j16. for testing
    t.timestamp('#1 ***** START DOWNLOAD *******');
    await download();
    t.timestamp('#2 ***** START MANTRACK.INIT *******');
    await mantrack.init('082j16');
    t.timestamp('#3 ***** START MANTRACK.ADDTRACK *******');
    await mantrack.addtrack(Pixel(7652, 1784));
    await mantrack.addtrack(Pixel(7714, 1862));
    ok = true;
    t.timestamp('#4 ***** OK = TRUE *******');
    setState(() {
      //refresh UI
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        t.timestamp("#999 **** BUILD COMPLETE *******");
      });
    });
  }

  download() async {
    t.timestamp('Download Started');
    String url =
        "http://www.erybus.com/oz3/Canada/topographic/routes/LakeBonavista2/082j16.png";
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    final appDir = await path_provider.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final phoneDir1 = path.join(appDir.path, 'phonetemp');
    final phoneDir2 = path.join(appDir.path, 'phone');
    bool phonethere = await io.Directory(phoneDir1).exists();
    if (!phonethere) {
      await io.Directory(phoneDir1).create();
      await io.Directory(phoneDir2).create();
    }
    final localPath = path.join(appDir.path, 'phone/082j16.png');
    final csvFile = io.File(localPath);
    await csvFile.writeAsBytes(response.bodyBytes);
    t.timestamp('Download Finished'); /* WHY DOES THIS print last */
    return;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    t.timestamp('#8 WIDGET BUILD START  ok = $ok');
    /* copy mantrack & add crosshairs */
    if (ok) {
      img.Image mapcopy = img.copyRotate(mantrack.mantrack!, angle: 0); //copy
      img.Image mapshow = mantrack.addcrosshairs(mapcopy, Pixel(7652, 1784));
      return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: Text("peter61 deleteme")),
          body: InteractiveViewer(
              minScale: 0.5,
              maxScale: 100.0,
              child: Image.memory(
                img.encodePng(mapshow),
                height: double.infinity,
                width: double.infinity,
                /*     fit: BoxFit.none,  */
              )));
    } else {
      return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    }
  }
}
```

peter61_mantrack.dart

```
// mantrack.dart
// draws track and crosshairs on a map image:  mapid
// Peter Thompson Oct 2023

import 'package:flutter/services.dart'; // for Uint8List, rootbundle
import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;
import 'dart:io' as io; //for file read/write
import 'datamodelgps.dart'; //for Pixel class
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart' as path_provider;
import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;

class ManTrack {
  img.Image? mantrack; // Future instatniated by init()
  img.Image? crosshairs;

  /* initialize crosshairs & mantrack to img.Image */
  init(String mapid) async {
    print('mantrack.init started');
    // instantiate crosshairs
    ByteData bytes1 = await rootBundle.load("assets/crosshairs.png");
    List<int> bytes2 = Uint8List.view(bytes1.buffer);
    crosshairs = img.decodeImage(Uint8List.fromList(bytes2));
    print('crosshairs instantiated,  Now for mantrack');

    // instantiate mantrack
    mapid = mapid + ".png";
    io.Directory appDir =
        await path_provider.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String mappath = path.join(appDir.path, 'phone', mapid); // 031e0.png
    print('mappath = $mappath');
    mantrack = await img.decodePngFile(mappath); //SLOW_SLOW 46 seconds!! //
    print('mantrack.init Finished');
    print('IMG.IMAGE (mantrack) FORMAT = ${mantrack!.format}');
    print('IMG.IMAGE (mantrack) WIDTH = ${mantrack!.width}');
    print('IMG.IMAGE (mantrack) HEIGHT = ${mantrack!.height}');
    print('IMG.IMAGE (mantrack) ISEMPTY = ${mantrack!.isEmpty}');
    print('IMG.IMAGE (mantrack) LENGTH = ${mantrack!.length}');
    print('IMG.IMAGE (mantrack) BYTE LENGTH = ${mantrack!.lengthInBytes}');
    print('IMG.IMAGE (mantrack) CHANNELS = ${mantrack!.numChannels}');
    print('IMG.IMAGE (mantrack) Size (bytes) row of pixels = ${mantrack!.rowStride}');
  }

  addtrack(Pixel p) {
    print('mantrack addtrack started');
    // add new gps track,  copy mantrack to mapshow
    img.fillRect(mantrack!,
        x1: (p.x - 13),
        y1: (p.y - 13),
        x2: (p.x + 13),
        y2: (p.y + 13),
        color: img.ColorRgba8(255, 0, 255, 200));
  }

  /* this is called from build */
  img.Image addcrosshairs(img.Image maptemp, Pixel p) {
    print('mantrack addcrosshairs started');
    // add crosshairs to mapshow
    img.Image composite = img.compositeImage(
      maptemp,
      crosshairs!,
      dstX: p.x - 190,
      dstY: p.y - 190,
    );
    print('mantrack addcrosshairs finished');
    return (composite);
  }
}
```

timestamp.dart

```
class Time {
  // constructor sets timeinit to now in seconds.
  int timeinit = 0;
  Time() {
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    this.timeinit = now.minute * 60 + now.second;
  }

  void timestamp(String desc) {
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    int elapsed = (now.minute * 60 + now.second) - timeinit;
    print('$desc = $elapsed seconds');
  }
}
```

datamodelgps.dart

```
class Pixel {
  int x;
  int y;
  Pixel(this.x, this.y); //constructor

  /* https://coflutter.com/dart-how-to-print-an-object/  */
  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Pixel: {x: ${x}, y: ${y} }';
  }
}
```

peter64_main.dart

```
// peter64.dart
// brendan-duncan github
// Peter Thompson Oct 2023
//
// AND DON'T FORGET ...
// dart pub add image
// dart pub add path_provider
// dart pub add path
// dart pub add http
// dart pub add image_size_getter
//
// pubspec.yaml assets/   ADD  assets/crosshairs.png
// peter64/android/app/src/main/manifest.xml
//      add ...application<... android:largeHeap=true>...

import 'package:flutter/material.dart'; // for BOILERPLATE runApp() etc
import 'timestamp.dart';
import 'mantrack.dart';
import 'datamodelgps.dart';
// import 'dart:io' as io; //for file read/write
// import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;

Time t = new Time();

// BOILERPLATE
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: Home());
  }
}

//ignore: must_be_immutable
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  ManTrack mantrack = ManTrack();
  bool ok = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    t.timestamp('#0 ***** START INITSTATE *******');
    initiate();
    super.initState();
  }

  initiate() async {
    // download 082j16. for testing
    t.timestamp('#1 ***** START DOWNLOAD 082j16*******');
    await mantrack.download();
    t.timestamp('#1 ***** END DOWNLOAD 082j16 *******');
    t.timestamp('#2 ***** START FILETOIMAGE() *******');
    await mantrack.fileToImage();
    t.timestamp('#2 ***** END FILETOIMAGE() *******');
    t.timestamp('#3 ***** START UI.IMAGE TO IMG.IMAGE *******');
    await mantrack.initmantrack(); // ui.image to img.image == mantrack
    t.timestamp('#3 ***** END UI.IMAGE TO IMG.IMAGE *******');
    t.timestamp('#4 ***** START CROSSHAIRS INIT  *******');
    await mantrack.crosshairsInit();
    t.timestamp('#4 ***** END CROSSHAIRS INIT  *******');
    t.timestamp('#5 ***** START ADDTRACK *******');
    await mantrack.addtrack(Pixel(7652, 1784));
    await mantrack.addtrack(Pixel(7714, 1862));
    t.timestamp('#5 ***** END ADDTRACK *******');

    /*******************   ************* */
    t.timestamp('SS#1 ***** START ADD CROSSHAIRS *******');
    await mantrack.addcrosshairs(Pixel(7714, 1862));
    t.timestamp('SS#1 ***** END ADD CROSSHAIRS *******');
    t.timestamp('SS#1 ***** START IMG TO UI IMAGE *******');
    await mantrack.convertImageToFlutterUi();
    t.timestamp('SS#1 ***** END IMG TO UI IMAGE *******');

    ok = true;
    t.timestamp('#4 ***** OK = TRUE *******');
    setState(() {
      //refresh UI

      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        t.timestamp("#999 **** BUILD COMPLETE *******");
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    t.timestamp('#8 WIDGET BUILD START  ok = $ok');
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      t.timestamp("#999 **** BUILD COMPLETE *******");
    });
    if (ok) {
      // mapshow = mantrack.readfile()
      // String url =
      //   "http://www.erybus.com/oz3/Canada/topographic/routes/LakeBonavista2/082j16.jpg";
      //  img.Image mapcopy = img.copyRotate(mantrack.mantrack!, angle: 0); //copy
      //  img.Image mapshow = mantrack.addcrosshairs(mapcopy, Pixel(7652, 1784));
      print("BUILDING SCAFFOLD START");
      print(mantrack.mapFile);
      return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: Text("peter64 deleteme4")),
          body: InteractiveViewer(
              minScale: 0.5,
              maxScale: 100.0,
              /*     child: Image.file(
                mantrack.mapFile!,
                scale: 1.0,
                repeat: ImageRepeat.noRepeat,
                height: double.infinity,
                width: double.infinity,
                /*     fit: BoxFit.none,  */
              ) */
              child: RawImage(
                  image: mantrack.uiShow,
                  height: double.infinity,
                  width: double.infinity)));
    } else {
      return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    }
  }
}
```

peter64_mantrack.dart

```
// mantrack.dart
// draws track and crosshairs on a map image:  mapid
// Copied from peter003_imgfinal.dart   MOVE TO peter56_try1
// https://github.com/brendan-duncan/image/blob/main/doc/flutter.md
// Peter Thompson Oct 2023

import 'package:flutter/services.dart'; // for Uint8List, rootbundle
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;
import 'dart:io' as io; //for file read/write
import 'datamodelgps.dart'; //for Pixel class
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart' as path_provider;
import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;


class ManTrack {
  img.Image? mantrack; // Future instatniated by init()
  img.Image? crosshairs;
  img.Image? composite;
  io.File? mapFile;
  ui.Image? uiImage;
  ui.Image? uiShow;
  int mapwidth = 8192; //? = uiImage from .jpg  ???? real size = 10089
  int mapheight = 6322; //? = uiImage from .jpg  ???? real size = 7786

  download() async {
    String url =
        "http://www.erybus.com/oz3/Canada/topographic/routes/LakeBonavista2/082j16.jpg";
    http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    final appDir = await path_provider.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final phoneDir1 = path.join(appDir.path, 'phonetemp');
    final phoneDir2 = path.join(appDir.path, 'phone');
    bool phonethere = await io.Directory(phoneDir1).exists();
    if (!phonethere) {
      await io.Directory(phoneDir1).create();
      await io.Directory(phoneDir2).create();
    }
    final localPath = path.join(appDir.path, 'phone/082j16.jpg');
    mapFile = io.File(localPath);
    print('LOCALPATH = $localPath');
    print('mapFile = $mapFile');
    await mapFile!.writeAsBytes(response.bodyBytes);
    print("BYTES IN RESPONSE.BODYBytes = ${response.contentLength}");
    /* contentlength = filesize saved locally  = erybus.com filesize
       jpeg = 27,331,477 bytes (lossy compression)
       Total Size wxhx3 for RGB = 10089 x 7786 x 3 = 235,658,862 bytes (0.2GB)
       png filesize = 56,234,914 bytes (lossless compression)
    */
    print(response.headers);

    return;
  }

  fileToImage() async {
    Uint8List bytes = mapFile!.readAsBytesSync();
    // ByteData bytes2 = ByteData.view(bytes.buffer); // not used
    ui.Codec codec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(bytes);
    ui.FrameInfo frame = await codec.getNextFrame();
    uiImage = frame.image;
    print('UI IMAGE COMPLETE - PROPERTIES BELOW');
    print('height = ${uiImage!.height}  width =  ${uiImage!.width}');
      /* height = 6322 width = 8192 ???  */ 
    return;
  }

  /* convert UI Image to IMG Image Library */
  initmantrack() async {
    ByteData? uibytes = await uiImage!.toByteData(); // ui to bytes
    print('lengthInBytes==>');
    print(uibytes!.lengthInBytes);
    mantrack = img.Image.fromBytes(
        width: mapwidth,
        height: mapheight,
        bytes: uibytes.buffer,
        numChannels: 4); // bytes to img
    print('initmantrack() complete ==> ui to img');
    print('IMG.IMAGE (mantrack) FORMAT = ${mantrack!.format}');
    print('IMG.IMAGE (mantrack) WIDTH = ${mantrack!.width}');
    print('IMG.IMAGE (mantrack) HEIGHT = ${mantrack!.height}');
    print('IMG.IMAGE (mantrack) ISEMPTY = ${mantrack!.isEmpty}');
    print('IMG.IMAGE (mantrack) LENGTH = ${mantrack!.length}');
    print('IMG.IMAGE (mantrack) BYTE LENGTH = ${mantrack!.lengthInBytes}');
    print('IMG.IMAGE (mantrack) CHANNELS = ${mantrack!.numChannels}');
    print('IMG.IMAGE (mantrack) Size (bytes) row of pixels = ${mantrack!.rowStride}');
    return;
  }

  /* initialize crosshairs & mantrack to img.Image */
  crosshairsInit() async {
    print('mantrack.init started');
    // instantiate crosshairs
    ByteData bytes1 = await rootBundle.load("assets/crosshairs.png");
    List<int> bytes2 = Uint8List.view(bytes1.buffer);
    crosshairs = img.decodeImage(Uint8List.fromList(bytes2));
    print('crosshairs instantiated,  Now for mantrack');
  }

  addtrack(Pixel p) {
    print('mantrack addtrack started');
    // add new gps track,  copy mantrack to mapshow
    img.fillRect(mantrack!,
        x1: (p.x - 13),
        y1: (p.y - 13),
        x2: (p.x + 13),
        y2: (p.y + 13),
        color: img.ColorRgba8(255, 0, 255, 200));
  }

  /* this is called from build */
  addcrosshairs(Pixel p) {
    print('mantrack addcrosshairs started');
    // add crosshairs to copy of mantrack
    composite = img.copyRotate(mantrack!, angle: 0); //OLD copy
/*  img.Image composite = img.Image.from(mantrack!); */ //new version of copy
    composite = img.compositeImage(
      composite!,
      crosshairs!,
      dstX: p.x - 190,
      dstY: p.y - 190,
    );
    print('mantrack addcrosshairs finished');
    print('COMPOSITE FORMAT = ${composite!.format}');
    print('COMPOSITE WIDTH = ${composite!.width}');
    print('COMPOSITE HEIGHT = ${composite!.height}');
    print('COMPOSITE ISEMPTY = ${composite!.isEmpty}');
    print('COMPOSITE LENGTH = ${composite!.length}');
    print('COMPOSITE BYTE LENGTH = ${composite!.lengthInBytes}');
    print('COMPOSITE CHANNELS = ${composite!.numChannels}');
    print('COMPOSITE Size (bytes) row of pixels = ${composite!.rowStride}');

    return;
  }

  convertImageToFlutterUi() async {
    print('START CONVERTIMAGETOFLUTTERUI');
    if (composite == null) {
      print('COMPOSITE = NULL');
    }
    print('COMPOSITE ISEMPTY = ${composite!.isEmpty}');
    ui.ImmutableBuffer buffer =
        await ui.ImmutableBuffer.fromUint8List(composite!.toUint8List());

    ui.ImageDescriptor id = ui.ImageDescriptor.raw(buffer,
        height: composite!.height,
        width: composite!.width,
        pixelFormat: ui.PixelFormat.rgba8888);

    ui.Codec codec = await id.instantiateCodec(
        targetHeight: composite!.height, targetWidth: composite!.width);

    ui.FrameInfo fi = await codec.getNextFrame();
    uiShow = fi.image;

    print('convertImageToFlutterUi complete');

    return;
  }
}
```